# PHP MYSQL query shortcut?

Tags: php, mysql

If I am doing a PHP MYSQL select of a table using the where clause that will return only 1 result, is there a simpler way to do this:

```
$result = mysql_query("select * FROM cart WHERE ID='".$cartID."'") or die(mysql_error());
$cartrec = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Is the `$cartrec = mysql_fetch_array($result);` needed or could I just do:
`$cartrec = mysql_query("select * FROM cart WHERE ID='".$cartID."'") or die(mysql_error());`

or is there a better syntax to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mysql_query` gets a *result set* (actually, a *resource* that refers to a result set) based on your query. This is the set of records that match your query.

`mysql_fetch_array` gets the first record from a result set, and returns it as an array.

So, up until you've called `mysql_fetch_array`, you haven't gotten the data in a usable format.

**Side note:** Consider using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score 2):

The fetch array is required, the mysql_query gets a result set (ressource), then mysql_fetch_array get's the element in the result set.

As a side note, be careful of SQL injections: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

EDIT: Might be a bit more advanced that what you need, but it might be worth while looking into PDO: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: Incorrect. The query is executed after `mysql_query`, but the return is a *resource*, from which you have to fetch records/rows.

Comment: Right, sorry, thought that the standard mysql_query was unbuffered, I was wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

> Is the $cartrec = mysql_fetch_array($result); needed

Yes, otherwise you get a resource pointer not an result set (array).

> or is there a better syntax to use?

Yes, [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Answer (score 1):

No, but its pretty common for people to write their own function for this use case. It's usually named something like fetch_one($sqlString) or fetch_first($sqlString)

Answer (score 0):

You could use this, but if the database structure were to change, it would be problematic

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

echo $row[0]; //column 1
echo $row[1]; //column 2
```

You may want to look at this http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php